# Display users who logged in, who logged out

Tags: bash, shell

My task:

> Write a program that outputs information about users in the system after a certain time interval: who entered, who left.

I tried to do it differently by comparing two files. I don't know how well I do it. `comm` is not very good here, I know. I tried using `diff` , but her output to the console is incomprehensible to me, and when I tried `diff -q`, I got only this line `Files 1.txt and 2.txt differ`

Please help me.

```
#!/bin/bash
while (true) do
who > 1.txt
sleep 10s
who > 2.txt
(comm -13 1.txt 2.txt) > 3.txt
(comm -23 2.txt 1.txt) > 4.txt
echo IN :
cat 3.txt 
echo OUT :
sleep 10s
cat 4.txt 
echo [______________________________________________________________]
done
```

upd: or better like this..idk

```
#!/bin/bash
while (true) do
who > 1.txt
sleep 10s
who > 2.txt
(comm -13 1.txt 2.txt) > 3.txt
echo IN :
cat 3.txt 
echo OUT :
sleep 10s
who > 2.txt
(comm -23 3.txt 2.txt) > 4.txt
cat 4.txt 
echo [______________________________________________________________]
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
who >1.txt
sleep 10
who >2.txt
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $1}' 1.txt 2.txt >3.txt

awk 'BEGIN{print "Below are the New users logged in now "}{print $0}' 3.txt

echo "=========================="

awk 'NR ==FNR {a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $1}' 2.txt 1.txt > 4.txt


awk 'BEGIN{print "Below are the user who logged out now"}{print $0}' 4.txt
```

Comment: Oh, thank you!!! But could you please tell us about this line `awk 'NR==NR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print $1}'` and about this `awk 'BEGIN{print "Below are the New users logged in now"}{print $0}' 3.txt `in more detail?I'm just not good at this syntax and I'll be very grateful if you explain a little more to me.

Comment: Could you please tell me what `NR==FNR`and `next` means?